# Intercept TLS/HTTP/2 from browsers

Tags: ssl, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, wireshark, http2

I'm able to intercept traffic to and from Chrome by exporting the SSL key log and referencing it in Wireshark.

I want to compare Chrome's behavior with the behavior of the other major browsers though.  How can I get the keys from those browsers in a format that Wireshark will understand?

Specifically

- Edge
- IE11
- Opera
- Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe those browsers allow you to export the SSL key like Chrome and Firefox do, with perhaps the exception of Opera (as it’s a Chromium based browser). It should also be noted that Edge is in the process of transitioning to Chromium so it presumably will soon have this facility too.

Depending why you want to do this, an alternative to intercepting the traffic, is to set up a webserver and log the responses. Nghttpd for example allows you to see each of the frames received (and sent). I used this to investigate the different prioritisation schemes used by the browsers [as discussed in my book](https://livebook.manning.com/book/http2-in-action/chapter-7/section-7-3-4) (sign up for a free account to read this section for free for a few mins each day). Basically I created a dummy page with a few resource types and fired up an nghttpd server in the directory with that page in verbose mode and grepped for the frame info I was looking for:

```
nghttpd -v 443 server.key server.crt | grep -E "PRIORITY|path|weight"
```

and then requested http://localhost from each browser I was interested in and saw the frame details each browser sent.

Comment: That's a good idea, will that log out the same detail as the Wireshark trace does (with regards to HTTP/2, not the lower protocols).

Comment: Yup it logs out the full HTTP/2 frame details if you use the `-v` flag when running nghttpd.

Comment: Is the best was to run it on Windows to use a Docker container?  I can't see anything that looks like no-fuss.

Comment: Sorry can’t help there. I used a Linux server I had access to and it would be similar for a mac, but Windows is a whole different kettle of fish. It does look like it’s possible with Cygwin from documentation: https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2/blob/master/README.rst but, as you say, far from no-fuss.